# Query to get data from Mongodb which matches all columns

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have documents as show below in the mongodb. Please let me know how to get latest document which matches Domain, hostname and service (all three fields should match) in C#.

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53e1373e9c2e1805dd895cbd"),
    "service" : "RAM__Usage",
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2014-08-08T19:59:47.913Z"),
    "hostname" : "HOSTXYZ",
    "Domain" : "DOMXYZ"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53e1373e9c2e1805dd895abd"),
    "service" : "RAM__Usage",
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2014-09-09T19:59:47.913Z"),
    "hostname" : "HOSTXYZ",
    "Domain" : "DOMXYZ"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53e1373e9c2e1805dd895abe"),
    "service" : "CPU__Usage",
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2014-09-09T19:59:47.913Z"),
    "hostname" : "HOSTXYZ",
    "Domain" : "DOMXYZ"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53e1373e9c2e1805dd895aff"),
    "service" : "RAM__Usage",
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2014-06-06T19:59:47.913Z"),
    "hostname" : "HOSTABC",
    "Domain" : "DOMABC"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53e1373e9c2e1805dd895agc"),
    "service" : "CPU__Usage",
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2014-07-07T19:59:47.913Z"),
    "hostname" : "HOSTABC",
    "Domain" : "DOMABC"
}
```

Comment: Solution :                                                    var query = Query.And(Query.EQ("Domain", "DOMXYZ"), Query.EQ("hostname", "HOSTXYZ"), Query.EQ("service", "RAM_USAGE"));
var bsonCursor = GetMongoDatabase().GetCollection<MentionYourClassName>(collection).Find(query).SetSortOrder(SortBy.Descending("timestamp")).SetLimit(1);
foreach (YourClassName objYourClassName in bsonCursor)
{
 //Do your task
}

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

```
    var query = Query.And(Query.EQ("Domain", "DOMXYZ"), Query.EQ("hostname", "HOSTXYZ"), Query.EQ("service", "RAM_USAGE"));

   //Gets the latest record from MongoDB matching given fileds
    var bsonCursor = GetMongoDatabase().GetCollection<YourClassName(YourMongoDBCollectionName).Find(query).SetSortOrder(SortBy.Descending("timestamp")).SetLimit(1);

    foreach (YourClassName objYourClassName in bsonCursor)
    {
        //Do your task
    }
```